# Compare columns in 2 files, append data for shared items and print the non shared items of the first file

Tags: awk

I have found similar questions as mine but none helped me with my specific problem (and i'm not quite sure whether there actually is such an easy solution..)

I have two files:

file1:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

file2:

```
a b x y z
d e x
f h i
```

Desired Output:

```
a b c x y z
d e f x
g h i
```

So, I want all the rows and columns from file 1 and additionally, if there is a match of the first two columns in file 2, I want to append the rest of those columns (from file 2) to the ones in file 1 and write it in a new file.

I have tried with awk but so far I have only managed to append the columns for those rows that have a match, but the other ones (in my example the "g,h,i" row) is not printed.
Another issue seems to be that the items in file 2 do not always have the same amount of columns.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try anything to solve the problem?

Comment: you'll benefit more if you post your attempted solution and get feedback on what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{k=$1$2; $1=$2=""; a[k]=$0; next}
     { if($1$2 in a){print $0a[$1$2] } else print $0}' file2 file1 | tr -s ' '
```

The output:

```
a b c x y z
d e f x
g h i
```

---

`FNR==NR` - ensures performing the first file

`k=$1$2;` - `k` is a key for associative array which accumulates all column values from the second file except the first two columns(as they become a key/hash). For ex. for the first `file2` line the array will be indexeed as `a['ab']='x y z'`

Comment: Thanks! could you please explain this a little? what exactly does the k mean? for me the output is unfortunately , that the third element from file 1 is appended at the very end, after the addition from file 2.

Comment: note that this method may have unfortunate side effects.  Assume the lines start with `a ab ...` and `aa b ...`.

Comment: Your solution is fine if the keys are of constant length or fields of different types (e.g. one alpha the other numeric). Just try a different input file as I suggested, you'll see the concern I was raising.

Comment: @karakfa, what is your solution/suggestion against *unfortunate side effects* ?

Comment: either use the field separator between the fields as in my solution, or with `($1,$2)` notation use the implicit multi dimensional array field delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

here is another `awk`

```
 awk        '{k=$1 FS $2} 
     NR==FNR {sub(k,"",$0); a[k]=$0; next} 
     k in a  {$0 = $0 a[k]}1' file2 file1

a b c x y z
d e f x
g h i
```

note the order of the files.